# Does zipping dynamic assets (JSON) improve performance?

Tags: reactjs, json, http, frontend

Is it possible to receive JSON data in .zip format on the front end, unzip and use it there and does that improve performance or not? I haven't seen it so far, but couldn't find any data on why you shouldn't do it.

PROs: smaller network traffic, faster fetching of data

CONs: additional handling of the data (zipping on the back end, unzipping on the front end)

Another issue I suspect is zipping JSONs is not very efficient (has low compression rate).

Comment: The browser can already do this for you if your server supports it. It's called gzip (or brotli)

Comment: `I haven't seen it so far,` on the contrary, it's used transparently by most sites through HTTP compression. `zipping JSONs is not very efficient (has low compression rate).` quite the opposite, text contains a *lot* of whitespace and repetitive text. In all web servers you can configure HTTP compression, the compression level and how to handle static vs dynamic content. Obviously, the server can compress static assets just once while dynamic responses need to be compressed every time.